# Trying to get enum style choices= working for django but the whole tuplets are appearing in the drop down

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Im using appengine and the appenginepatch (so my issue could be related to that)

I have set up a model with a property that has several choices but when trying to display on a form or via admin interface I am getting an error:

> Property mode is 'o'; must be one of (('s', 'Single'), ('m', 'Multi'), ('o', 'Ordered'))

This is my code:

```
MODES = (
  ('s', 'Single'),
  ('m', 'Multi'),
  ('o', 'Ordered')
)

class X(search.SearchableModel):
    mode = models.StringProperty( default='s', choices=MODES )
```

if I set it to use Integers (as below) the admin form (and my own ModelForm) shows each option for the property as the whole tuplet so that when I select and try to save I get the error that I'm not saving an Integer value

```
MODES = (
  (0, 'Single'),
  (1, 'Multi'),
  (2, 'Ordered')
)

class X(search.SearchableModel):
    mode = models.IntegerProperty( default=0, choices=MODES )
```

Is there something special I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue in Django/appengine support.  It's documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=72) on the google-app-engine-django bug tracker, but it's closed as "wontfix" there.  It is also documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=350) on the googleappengine bug tracker and is closed as invalid.

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property), the appengine `choices` parameter works different than the Django one.  You do not appear to be able to do what you want without creating a custom widget.  According to Guido's comment closing the googleappengine ticket,

> I realize that this may cause problems
>   when you're trying to create a form
>   from the model, but the solution is to
>   override the form field using a custom
>   widget and passing the list of desired
>   choices to the widget.  (There's an
>   example of this in Rietveld, in
>   codereview/views.py, class
>   SettingForm.)

Comment: Ah great thanks, I couldn't find those references. The workaround should be good enough. Cheers